# Cisco 1841 Router Error

Tags: router

The ROMMON mode displays this continuously.

```
System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(13r)T, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 2006 by cisco Systems, Inc.
PLD version 0x10
GIO ASIC version 0x127
c1841 platform with 131072 Kbytes of main memory
Main memory is configured to 64 bit mode with parity disabled


Readonly ROMMON initialized
program load complete, entry point: 0x8000f000, size: 0xcb80
open(): Open Error = -13
boot: cannot open "flash::"
boot: cannot determine first executable file name on device "flash::"
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Problem Description
>
> The compact flash (CF) contained in specific Cisco routers may contain a defect preventing access to the Compact Flash and could cause a boot failure following a power cycle or reload. During a failed state the router will be unable to pass traffic. Cisco is providing a ROM Monitor (ROMmon) update that resolves this scenario.
>   Background
>
> The Compact Flash modules were installed in specific Cisco routers that were manufactured between May 2005 and October 2006. In addition, spare Compact Flash Modules shipped individually between May 2005 and October 2006 may exhibit this problem.
>
> This issue has been linked to a Compact Flash vendor manufacturing problem. The root cause was identified and appropriate steps have been taken to resolve the problem. An upgrade to the router ROM Monitor (ROMmon) is available as a solution.

The solution to this issue is to grab the update to the ROMmon software from Cisco and install it.  Download links as well as instructions are available [from Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/620/fn62573.html)